# Symfony no me toma el controlador de una API

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, sylius

Estoy realizando una API en un framework llamado Sylius que utiliza el framework symfony como base.
Actualmente no me reconoce la clase del controlador de la API que resuelve la lógica de la API

Tengo un controlador con su respectiva declaración:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace EasyCommerce\ShopApiPlugin\Controller\Order;

use EasyCommerce\ShopApiPlugin\Factory\ValidationErrorViewFactoryInterface;
use EasyCommerce\ShopApiPlugin\Request\Order\CustomerOrderCancellationRequest;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

final class CustomerOrderCancellationAction
{
    /** @var ViewHandlerInterface */
    private $viewHandler;

    /** @var MessageBusInterface */
    private $bus;

    /** @var ValidatorInterface */
    private $validator;

    /** @var ValidationErrorViewFactoryInterface */
    private $validationErrorViewFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ViewHandlerInterface $viewHandler,
        MessageBusInterface $bus,
        ValidatorInterface $validator,
        ValidationErrorViewFactoryInterface $validationErrorViewFactory
    ) {
        $this->viewHandler = $viewHandler;
        $this->bus = $bus;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->validationErrorViewFactory = $validationErrorViewFactory;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        $pickupRequest = new CustomerOrderCancellationRequest($request);
        $validationResults = $this->validator->validate($pickupRequest);

        if (0 === count($validationResults)) {
            $this->bus->dispatch($pickupRequest->getCommand());

            return $this->viewHandler->handle(View::create(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT));
        }

        return $this->viewHandler->handle(View::create($this->validationErrorViewFactory->create($validationResults), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));
    }
}
```

El controlador lo declaro de la siguiente forma:

```
<service id="sylius.shop_api_plugin.controller.order.customer_order_cancellation_action"
                 class="EasyCommerce\ShopApiPlugin\Controller\Order\CustomerOrderCancellationAction"
        >
            <argument type="service" id="fos_rest.view_handler" />
            <argument type="service" id="sylius_shop_api_plugin.command_bus" />
            <argument type="service" id="validator" />
            <argument type="service" id="sylius.shop_api_plugin.factory.validation_error_view_factory" />
 </service>
```

La ruta la declaro de la siguiente forma:

```
sylius_shop_api_customer_order_cancellation:
    path: /orders/{tokenValue}/cancellation
    methods: [PUT]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.shop_api_plugin.controller.order.customer_order_cancellation_action
```

Y me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Attempted to load class \"CustomerOrderCancellationAction\" from namespace \"EasyCommerce\\ShopApiPlugin\\Controller\\Order\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for another namespace?"
}
```

***Para probar si la ruta me quedó bien configurada lo apunté a otro controlador y funciona. El problema es con el controlador que cree.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eran dos espacios de nombres diferentes en el proyecto principal tuve que borrar cache:

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

Y posteriormente recargar el composer:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

De esa forma me vuelve a cargar todos los espacios de nombre